# twilio api sms notifications with python django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good evening everyone I had to implement the twilio module in my django project and it works well, the problem is that it does not allow you to send sms to phone numbers other than mine

Comment: is your twilio account currently a free trial account?

Comment: yes it is a free account

Answer (score 0):

I think sample code is like the following. You need set the two environment variables `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` and `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN`.

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    body="your message",
    from_='+15017122661',
    to='+15558675310'
)

print(message.sid)
```

Comment: sorry this code don't not permit to send sms for any phone number

Comment: can you show me the error message?